# Inequality which involves complex numbers and absolute values

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value

How can I solve the following inequality:
$|\frac{(1+(1-\theta)z)}{1-\theta z}| \leq 1$ ?
$z$ is a complex number. I have to find the values of $\theta$ for which the inequality is satisfied.

Comment: Solve it for what?

Comment: What are you trying to solve for? $z$? $\theta$? Both?

Comment: From the question I would say $\theta$ in terms of $z$. But is $\theta$ real or complex?

Comment: $\theta$ is real

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Multiply both sides with $|1-\theta z|$. Then use the real and imaginiary part on both sides to calculate the absolute values.

Comment: Please, could you write down the entire process? I still have problems